# How to get Postgres function name as well as function specific name from pg_catalog.pg_proc?

Tags: function, postgresql

Since Postgres supports function overloading, getting function name as well as function specific name(System generated without duplicates) is more meaning full.

Assume i have 2 functions in the name as Func1 which are overloaded as shown below,

```
  CREATE FUNCTION "Schema"."Func1"(IN param1 INTEGER,
  IN Param2 CHAR)
  RETURNS INTEGER
  AS $BODY$

  begin
  return param1+1;
  end  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;@


  CREATE FUNCTION "Schema"."Func1"(IN param1 INTEGER)
  RETURNS INTEGER
  AS $BODY$

  begin
  return param1+1;
  end  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;@
```

How do i load the functions as well as input parameters correctly from pg_catalog.pg_proc.
With the help of information_schema.routines, there is a way to load function 1)specific_name 2) routine_name

But many other attributes are missing in information_schema.routines like 1) isWindow function 2) isStrict function 3) isProRetSet function

So is there some other means to get the function specific_name from pg_catalog.....

Answer (score 9):

A general method is to use `psql -E` or set `ECHO_HIDDEN` inside psql and look at the queries it generates for backslash commands.

For instance, `\df "Func1"` produces this with PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE p.proname ~ '^(Func1)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

which gives you directions about how to get the different function signatures  associated to the name `"Func1"`

The same with `\df+` would lead to the other attributes, like volatility.

Comment: Thanks, pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as Argument_data_types, gives out data like "param1 integer, param2 character". so i have to write a parser to pares and get individual value like first parameter name is param1 and its datatype as integer and so on for each input parameter.Also there are other parameter related attributes like parameter_mode(IN,OUT,INOUT,VARIADIC) which can be easily retrieved from information_schema.routines. If there is a possibility to get specific function name(without duplicates) then it will be easy get the advantage of both .pg_proc as well as .routines...